OpportunityFieldHistory haven't registered lookup change
Last week i got some updates on opportunities on custom field Project__c but i don't know what has triggered the field update. From filled value it was settled into null value and when i do a soql query to search on changes of opportunityfieldhistory it doesn't show any changes but on last modified by is showing that it has been updated by me even without touching it.
The field is checked in history field tracking.


and before anyone tries to argue this, OpportunityFieldHistory is the right object to be querying here. The one that only contains stage/amount/close date is OpportunityHistory.
